# Read line from a text file and call the class to my main

Tags: java, class, interface, readline

I am learning super class, abstract class and abstract class, so I have to read a word from a file and depends of the word I found, make my program run one of three different methods. However, I got always this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - incompatible types: int cannot be converted to java.lang.String
    at encryption.EncryptorFactory.create(EncryptorFactory.java:23)
    at superencryptor.SuperEncryptor.main(SuperEncryptor.java:15)
C:\Users\Linda\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
```

Here is my main package where I am trying to run the program:

```
package superencryptor;

import encryption.EncryptorFactory;
import encryption.*;

public class SuperEncryptor
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String strTestData = "This is a test";
        /* V3 - using a factory */
        EncryptorFactory obFactory = new EncryptorFactory();
        IEncryptor obEncryptor = obFactory.create();

        String strOutEnc = obEncryptor.encrypt(strTestData);
        System.out.println("The encrypted value is: " + strOutEnc);
        String strOutDec = obEncryptor.decrypt(strOutEnc);
        System.out.println("The decrypted value is: " + strOutDec);
    }
}
```

Here is the method I am trying to run:

```
package encryptor;

public class BasicEncryptor implements IEncryptor
{
    @Override
    public String encrypt(String strData)  // "abc"
    {
        String strEncrypted = "";

        for (int nIndex = 0; nIndex < strData.length(); ++nIndex)
        {
            strEncrypted += strData.charAt(nIndex);  
            strEncrypted += "@";
        }

        return strEncrypted;
    }

    @Override
    public String decrypt(String strData) // "a@b@c@"
    {
        String strDecrypted = "";

        // Start at the first character (index = 0) and add 2 to it each time
        // through to skip the accompanying @ symbol.
        for (int nIndex = 0; nIndex < strData.length(); nIndex += 2)
        {
            strDecrypted += strData.charAt(nIndex);
        }

        return strDecrypted;
    }
}
```

Here is my interface:

```
package encryptor;

public interface IEncryptor
{
    public String encrypt(String strData);
    public String decrypt(String strData);
}
```

And the factory class:

```
package encryptor;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public  class EncryptorFactory
{
    public IEncryptor create() throws IOException
    {
        IEncryptor obEncryptor = null;

        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader ( "C:\\config.dat");
        try 
        {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            String line = br.readLine();

            if (  line.equals ("BasicEncrypto")&& br != null)
            {
                obEncryptor= new BasicEncryptor ();
            }

            br.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e);
        } 
        catch (NumberFormatException e) 
        {
            System.err.println("Invalid number");
        }
        return obEncryptor;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is in EncryptorFactory.java at line 23? there you assign an int value to a String variable. The error message does not match the code you show

Comment: The error message is quite clear.  You're trying to put an `int` where it wants a `String`.  You can't do that.

Comment: The basic problem is your `SuperEncryptor` uses an `EncryptorFactory` from the package `encryption` (ending in `ion`), and this is where the compilation problem is according to the stack trace. The `EncryptionFactory` class you are showing us is in the package `encryptor` (ending in `or`), so it is not the same, and it seems to me it doesn’t have the same compilation problem (Ihaven’t tried compiling it, though). So the solution seems to be: make sure you control which Java classes and packages you are using and which not.

Comment: Side note: you also have an unnecessary null check in your `EncryptorFactory.create()` - `br != null` can never be false at that point. And you should have a look at [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Answer (score 0):

What you really need is add the class cast in your code to transfer the type of int to the type of string. Here is the example for you:

`String sTest = Integer.toString(2);`

Comment: it was correct I had an encryption and I changed how ever it seems to have other trouble.. I really do not understand why it is trying to get an int if I am comparing two strings. please forgive me I really new at this.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\config.dat (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
 at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
 at encryptor.EncryptorFactory.create(EncryptorFactory.java:18)
 at superencryptor.SuperEncryptor.main(SuperEncryptor.java:16)

Comment: Could you please attach your code in the comments? Depends on your exception log, it seems you didn't notice the special meaning in double quotes usage. While you want to use "\" in double quotes as the path of your file location , remember add the "\" front it as the escape sequences. Hope the description would be helpful. 
Example:

`BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Documents\\test.txt")`

Comment: @AllenAn, `new FileReader ( "C:\\config.dat")` looks correct, the \  is escaped as it should be. Linda, is there supposed to be a file config.dat in the root of your C drive? If so, did you doublecheck that it is indeed there? Also it may be an issue with uppercase and lowercase file name: while Windows often doesn’t care, I imagine that Java might be more picky, so if for instance that file name has a capital C, make sure you write that in your Java program too.